# Determinant of matrix full of 1 with the subdiagonal full of 0

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd like to compute the determinant of a matrix of the following form:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & \ldots & \ldots  & \ldots & 1 \\
0 & \ddots &  & & \vdots \\
1 & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & \ldots & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Manually, I know that the determinant is equal to one up to $n=5$, and I cannot prove that this is the case for all $n$.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote by $d_n$ this determinant. Subtracting the line $L_1$ to each line $L_i$, $2\leqslant i\leqslant n$ gives :

$$d_n=\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & \ldots & \ldots  & \ldots & 1 \\
0 & \ddots &  & & \vdots \\
1 & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & \ldots & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right|
=
\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & \ldots & \ldots  & \ldots & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \ldots & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right|
$$
Then developping with respect to the last column gives :

$$d_n=(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^{n-1}=1$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very clear !